# Is it wrong to explain "appetizers" as "snacks we serve before the main dish"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I'm a teacher for beginners at an English course in Brazil, and I'd like to explain "appetizers" and "snacks" at the same time.

Is it ok if I explain **appetizers** as **snacks** we serve before the main dish?

Comment: That's a reasonable definition.  If you wish you can explain the etymology a bit, in that the purpose of the snacks is to enhance your appetite for the main course.

Answer (score 2):

According to [RusCusine.com](http://www.ruscuisine.com/recipes/appetizers/)

> **appetizers**, as in any cuisine culture, and Russia is not an exception,
>   serve as **small snacks** before main course. Russian appetizers (in
>   Russian, they are called “zakuski”) were meant mainly not to provoke
>   keen appetite but to have them with strong drinks.

(From what I have heard, what the Russians consider "small snacks" could substitute for a full meal, but I have no reference for this.)

In contrast, mothers often sternly tell their children; "No snacks before dinner! You'll ruin your appetite!"  But the snacks the mothers are talking about are usually junk food.

As for the dictionary definitions:

***snack***, defined by [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/snack)

> a small amount of food that is eaten between meals, or a very small
>   meal:
>
> I had a huge lunch, so I'll only need a snack for dinner

***appetizer***, defined by [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/appetizer)

> a small amount of food eaten before a meal
>
> At 6.30 everyone gathered for drinks and appetizers in the lounge.
>
> mainly US: the first part of a meal

Everyone would understand if the sample sentence above said:

> At 6:30 everyone gathered for drinks and snacks in the lounge.

(**Starter** is starting to be used in place of **appetizer** in the US, in places that want to project an upscale image.  The French (and others) use entrée. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entr%C3%A9e))

**Conclusion:** If you go by the dictionary definitions, using snack for appetizer or starter is not strictly speaking correct, but in real life in my part of the world (east coast US), no one would care (except a child's mother.)

Comment: Except a child's mother +1